# How to get a for loop declaration to work with variables

Tags: bash, shell

When I use a variable in my for loop declaration the for loop only iterates one time.

I need to use a variable as I am calling this recursively, with a different directory each time.

The following works:

```
    for file in /path/to/dir/*; do
    ....
    done
```

Whereas this does not:

```
    test="/path/to/dir/*"
    for file in $test; do
    ....
    done
```

Comment: How does it not work? The two snippets you've posted are essentially identical, since unquoted parameter expansions undergo pathname expansion. If there's a difference, it's due to the code you aren't showing.

Comment: I tested it out, and it seems that is working, using your code.

Comment: What would not work is `for file in "$test"; do` because the quoting of the variable prevents the expansion. See: [ShellCheck: SC2066](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2066)

Comment: It's best not to put wildcards in variables, since they only expand when the variable is used without double-quotes, and non-double-quoted variable references can cause other problems. Instead, apply the wildcard when the var is used: `test="/path/to/dir"; for file in "$test"/*; do ...`

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to store the expanded wildcard in an array:

```
files=( /path/to/dir/* )
for file in "${files[@]}"; do ...
```